# Flutter Calendar Carousel selection shifts the calendar dates

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using flutter calendar carousel version 1.4.0 and experiencing this strange behaviour that when I shift the month and select a day (only first selection), the calendar shifts by 1 day. I'm  attaching the code and a gif for behaviour of the calendar.

**Gif**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGQd4.gif

**Code**:

```
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap;
  Widget _calendarWidget() {
    return Container(
      //alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0),
      child: CalendarCarousel<Event>(
        onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
          this.setState(() => _selectedDate = date);
        },
        weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        headerTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Nunito', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: FontSize.m, color: Colors.deepPurple),[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        selectedDayButtonColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        selectedDayBorderColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        weekFormat: false,
        markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
        selectedDateTime: _selectedDate,
        daysHaveCircularBorder: null, /// null for not rendering any border, true for circular border, false for rectangular border
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may encounter the same issue, I did some hit and trial and the error is due to "showHeader" field in CalendarCarousel, deactivating the same and giving a custom header, solved my issue.